# Max number of missions per day (24 real time hours)?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I have 7 [fleet command rooms](https://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Fleet_Command_Room) on my new freighter. I thought, that would increase the number of missions I get per day.

How can I get more then 5 missions per day (real time 24 hours)?
Does it depend on the size or class or even species on my freighter?

Answer (score 4):

At least on PC (in the Beyond update), the 5 missions per day is a game limitation that has nothing to do with the size of your freighter.